# PHPUnit test running all tests all the time

Tags: laravel, phpunit, composer-php

I am running Laravel 4 under Window and I have a problem when running phpunit.

Recently it wasn't working at all (just showing the help info, no matter what I was running).

After reinstalling, only removing and re-adding the package to composer.json, also running 'composer update', I realise that "phpunit app/tests/directory/fileTest.php" is running all my tests instead of only the fileTest.php one.

What might be happening, any ideas?

Comment: It might be related to the `phpunit.xml` configuration file. Take a look at this file to find out which tests are going to be executed.
If you want to run a specific test, you can use `--filter` option

Comment: No matter what I write after 'phpunit' seems to do same thing...